# tweet on twitter with fabric in android

Tags: android, twitter, tweets

how can i tweet with fabric ? but without dialog ?
i used this code to login:

```
 btnlog.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
           TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
            txt.setText(session.getUserName());
            //TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).text("test").show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do API requests from Fabric. See the docs: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/api

To do a status update:

```
Twitter.getApiClient().getStatusesService().update();
```

The parameters of this method will follow the same set as the POST statuses/update parameters.

Comment: Yes, Twitter kit has built in support to Single Sign on: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login

Comment: @Cipriani : Did you get any callback when posting tweet using TweetComposer ?